# Comparing data on two spreadsheets

Tags: excel, countif

I have data in two spreadsheets. In column A of both spreadsheets are customer numbers. I need to find the customer numbers in sheet 2 that are also in sheet 1. How best to do this? Using COUNTIF I guess. I have used this in the past but many moons ago and I am struggling to recall how to!

Comment: It's really not clear what you want to do. Do you want to return a value? If so the above comment does that. Do you want to just count how many appear on both sheets? Do you want them to order themselves? Conditional formatting? Highlighted? Please expand your question

Answer (score 1):

In sheet 2, use the formula:
`=NOT(ISNA(MATCH(Sheet2!A1,Sheet1!A:A,0)))` and copy the formula down.

For each item in Sheet 2, it will check if it is in Sheet 1 and return TRUE or FALSE.